# Testing a component that Fetches API (React - Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm kind of new at testing so I guess I have a pretty simple problem, I followed a tutorial about testing react components  that fetches API and I wrote it like this;

[image]

The MainPage here just fetches a basic football teams API exactly like shown in the mock fetch. It should return one icon and one name property.

As you can see there is an error, it expects a "promise" from what I've seen but shouldn't it expect HTML ? How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: Please add your code as a snippet to the question, do not use images for code.

Comment: As for the issue, you don't need to wrap `render` with `act`, that's already done internally by `react-testing-library`.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what the problem is without seeing the implementation of your . TypeScript works across the project, so the problem may be cause by another component.

At the moment, the problem I see is you are not returning your promise from the arrow function.